# Initialization of data attributes

Tags: python, class, function, attributes, member

I have a class like this

```
class SomeClass:
    def doSomething(self):
        self.counter = 50
```

I create an instance `x` for `SomeClass`

```
x = SomeClass()
```

When I try to get the value of counter like this: `x.counter` I get the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: SomeClass instance has no attribute 'counter'
```

But After I call the member function `x.doSomething()` and then look for the data attribute, it is available.

```
>>> x.doSomething()
>>> x.counter
50
```

Why is it like this? Won't all the data attributes be available as soon as the instance is created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `self.counter` is created only then `doSomething()` is called. In Python, instance attributes are dynamic and can be created at runtime. To have `self.counter` available from the creation of the object, put its initialization in a constructor:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = None
    def doSomething(self):
        self.counter = 50
```

Now all instances of `SomeClass` will have `self.counter` available from start, although its value will be `None` until `doSomething` is called. Natually, there are many variations on this theme to allow you to implement the exact semantics you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks. Is it a recommended practice to follow this? Or should we initialize all the data attributes in `__init__` ?

Comment: Looks like you d modified the answer to which answers my question in my previous comment. Thanks.

Comment: @bdhar: Unless you're doing something extra-funky, I would recomment having all your instance attributes initialized in the constructor.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the basic tutorial on OO programming with Python or OO in general

Comment: @pynator: I fail to see the connection between this question and "OO in general". Care to elaborate?